# AndroidStudio not automatically importing RoboLectric objects

Tags: unit-testing, android-studio, kotlin, import, robolectric-gradle-plugin

After setting up gradle properly, when i add for example `@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)` at the top of my test class, Andtoid studio does not import the class automatically when I click `Alt+Enter`.

When I manually type `import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner`, i see that the class is recognized.

I have already done **Invalidate Caches/Restart..**.

I am using **Kotlin** and **AndroidStudio 4.0** and **robolectric:4.3.1**.

Answer (score 2):

I had to use

```
androidTestImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.3.1'
```

instead of

```
testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.3.1'
```

i my module `build.gradle`.